# Upload of two different files, from two different inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I'm currently trying to handle the upload of two different files from two different `<input type="file"/>`s.

For example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddIssue", "Magazine", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<fieldset>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <div class="editor-label">Issue: </div>
            <input type="file" name="issueFile" id="issueFile"/>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <div class="editor-label">Cover: </div>
            <input type="file" name="issueCover" id="issueCover"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </fieldset>
}
```

I've figured out how to receive a file (or files) from one input, but can't find any appropriate information on how to receive files from multiple inputs.

I already have a method for POST, but can't figure out what shall I receive on post.

```
[HttpPost, Authorize]
public ActionResult AddIssue(string dummy)
{ }
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What does your Controller code look like? I can't see any obvious problems from this code

Comment: What does the controller action method look like?  What happens when it includes two arguments for files?

Comment: If i try to pass two HttpPostedFileBase instances as i did with receivin a single file from single input, i get null reference on both, also array of HttpPostedFileBase - same.

Comment: more please, where is the code that is getting the file data? You should just be able to add params for this, like so: `AddIssue(HttpPostedFileBase issueFile, HttpPostedFileBase issueCover)`

Comment: Tnx, musefan, for opening my eyes. I've forgotten (as i'm only learning), that the arguments both must have same names/ids as an inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the comment, here is a more specific solution...

You need to ensure that your Controller Action parameters are named the same as the `name` attribute on your form fields. This should work for you:

```
public ActionResult AddIssue(HttpPostedFileBase issueFile, HttpPostedFileBase issueCover)
{ }
```

Remember, it is the `name` attributes that are used to identify the fields from the controller. The `id` attributes mean nothing, and do not have to match.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've realy helped.

Comment: How to separate the posted files by name property afterwards. (I'm Newbie)